# React Native Render Buttons

Tags: reactjs, react-native, use-state, react-usememo

I think I know the issue but I don't have the solution,
so I have these buttons that I create with looping on useState arrray

```
const [booleanMonth,setMonth]=useState([
  {key:0,value:'January',title:'Jan',checked:false},
  {key:1,value:'February',title:'Feb',checked:false},
  {key:2,value:'March',title:'Mar',checked:false},
  {key:3,value:'April',title:'Apr',checked:false},
  {key:4,value:'May',title:'May',checked:false},
  {key:5,value:'June',title:'Jun',checked:false},
  {key:6,value:'July',title:'Jul',checked:false},
  {key:7,value:'August',title:'Aug',checked:false},
  {key:8,value:'September',title:'Sep',checked:false},
  {key:9,value:'October',title:'Oct',checked:false},
  {key:10,value:'November',title:'Nov',checked:false},
  {key:11,value:'December',title:'Dec',checked:false}
])
```

And then to render the buttons :

```
const createButtonMonth = useMemo(() =>{
console.log('createButtonMonth')
return (<View style={styles.containerForButtons2}>
        {
          booleanMonth.map((item,key) => 
            <View key={item.key} style={styles.buttonFilter3}>
            <Button style={styles.buttonFilter3}
            title={item.title} 
            value={booleanMonth[item.key].checked} 
            onCheckColor='red'
            color={booleanMonth[item.key].checked==true ? 'green':'black'}
            onPress={()=>onPressMonthFilter(booleanMonth[item.key].key,booleanMonth[item.key].checked)}
            /></View>)
        }
        </View>)
  },[booleanMonth])
```

now this is the onPress function which change the checked status to true or false, hence supposedly
change the color of those buttons

```
const onPressMonthFilter = (keyMonth,statusMonth) =>{
if(booleanMonth[keyMonth].checked==true){
  booleanMonth[keyMonth].checked=false
  console.log(booleanMonth)
  setMonth(booleanMonth)
}else{
  booleanMonth[keyMonth].checked=true
  console.log(booleanMonth)
  setMonth(booleanMonth)
}
setMonth(booleanMonth)
}
```

In the console log it returned with checked true or false , which means my code is correct but It doesnt render the right color , false = black , true = green

Help newbie reactjs user here please :<

Answer (score 1):

I think it's due to the memoization.

Try to remove the useMemo as it captures the components and prevents him from getting rerendered.